# Experiences with Datasnap

Tags: delphi, datasnap

We are thinking about the usage of a Delphi Datasnap Server in our company. But we are a little bit worrying about the less articles and support we found in the internet.

**So my questions are:**
Is someone really working with Datasnap?

How much users are using your Datasnap-Application simultaneously?

What are your experiences and what about the reliability?

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: See http://robertocschneiders.wordpress.com/2012/11/22/datasnap-analysis-based-on-speed-stability-tests/comment-page-1/#comment-71 for some performance information. In short: DataSnap can suffer some stability and performance issues.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I knew this site already. But i thought that maybe someone has REAL experiences

Comment: If, with default settings, DataSnap is not able to handle such basic concurrent testing, it is to be expected that there is some design problems. Any DataSnap server won't resist to a basic [DoS attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack). So in REAL world, with villains all around, experience may be disastrous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have implemented (or helped implementing) DataSnap servers for a handful of customers in the past year or two (some using a handful of different DataSnap Servers, DBX as well as REST). I have to ask, but I do not believe they get more than 100 concurrent user connections. There are some bugs in DataSnap - most are solved, although XE3 introuced a new one (which will be fixed by the upcoming update).
Deployment using ISAPI is most reliable. We use an SSL certificate for HTTPS traffic. There are some webinars, white papers and articles available by several developers. I've also written a Delphi DataSnap Development courseware manual (about to be updated for XE3 - after the first update is released, so the parameterised-query-bug is gone)...